# CosmosDB generic OrderBy query or get last data first

Tags: sql, linq, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm using the code from azure project, when CosmosDB is created first time. It has a nice generic `GetItemsAsync` method.

I have modified it a little to have following:

```
 public static async Task<List<T>> GetItemsAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, int maxItemCount = -1)
    {
        IDocumentQuery<T> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(
            UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId),
            new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = maxItemCount })
            .Where(predicate)
            .AsDocumentQuery();

        List<T> results = new List<T>();
        while (query.HasMoreResults)
        {
            results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>());
            if (maxItemCount != -1)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        return results;
    }
```

What I want to do is, in some calls to this method, I need to add `OrderBy` query. The problem is I have couple collections in same CosmosDB and fields are different. When I want to list one of the collections I just want to get latest ones.

So in this example, I actually send count as 50 so I will get only 50, but I also want to get recent ones. The above code returns oldest 50 as expected. Is there any solution this? I'm guessing there might be a way to get latest data first and when I call for 50, it would be latest 50 records.

Other thing I tried, was to create another method called `GetItemsWithOrderByAsync` and tried to give Expression>, but it requires so much modification in whole class to support TKey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after playing around, I came up with the following as a solution. Created new method and:

```
 public static async Task<List<T>> GetItemsWithOrderByAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<T, object>> orderByPredicated, int maxItemCount = -1)
    {
        IDocumentQuery<T> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(
            UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseId, CollectionId),
            new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = maxItemCount }).
            Where(predicate).
            OrderByDescending(orderByPredicated).
            AsDocumentQuery();

        List<T> results = new List<T>();
        while (query.HasMoreResults)
        {
            results.AddRange(await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>());
            if (maxItemCount != -1)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        return results;
    }
```

Comment: Your solution is exactly what I'm trying to achieve.   Can you share your code you used to build your 'orderByPredicated'  expression?  That is where I'm struggling.  I know how to build a predicate for a Where, but not the OrderBy piece.

Comment: @johnnyarguelles I have something like; `await CosmosDBRepository<X>.GetItemsWithOrderByAsync(n => {actualPredicate}, n => n.CreatedDate, count);` Hope that helps

Comment: @erincerol this was very helpful, using Expression<Func<T, object>> orderByPredicated is what I needed.